# How to get product via attribute value or label?

Tags: magento-2.1, product, attributes, product-attribute, custom-attributes

Can I retrieve a product using an attribute code and/or attribute value?
No product ID, no product name, just an attribute code and value.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use any product collection with `addAttributeToFilter` in your module model/block/controller/observer/etc. See the example below for a generic model. Replace **myattribute** with your attribute code and **myvalue** with the value.

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Model;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory;

class MyModel {

    protected $collectionFactory;

    public function __construct(
        CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
    ) {
        $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;      
    }

    public function getProductsByAttributeValue() {

        // Build Product collection, get name + sku
        $collection = $this->collectionFactory->create();
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect(['name','sku','myattribute']);

        // Only get products matching my attribute value
        $collection->addAttributeToFilter('myattribute', 'myvalue');

        return $collection;
    }   
}
```